# How can I implement auto join for XMPP room in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, ios9.1, groupchat

**I want to do Auto Join room in XMPP group chat.**

I have all of group created from back end Server, first time i join the room but when i disconnect from XMPP (out of the app) and back inside app and re-connect xmpp, I again need to join the room.

In side app one user already available in multiple room so not possible to Join again n again in the room . Please help..

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "You are a good question but you question hurt me. ;)" ..... Do share if you find any solution , I am to stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to show this link : https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html .
Here you can find the solution of Auto join and room storage.

Answer (score 0):

There is No way for , reEnter to your rooms Automatically.
you should make a loop in your group list ( rooms ) and Enter to each of them.
 i recommend  to  do it by operationQueue.

Comment: is that any option from backend Side ? Because more then 100 room join again n again not a good solution..

Comment: @SureshJagnani i don't know but i'm think , there is no way :)

Comment: Yes i understand but i assume anyway via Set Pubsub node. do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: Well said! joining 1000 rooms using loop? that's what I am trying to avoid.